# MessageImpl does not implement Message

Tags: go

In golang, I'm having the following compile error:

```
cannot use m (type MessageImpl) as type Message in assignment:
    MessageImpl does not implement Message (missing FirstLine method)
```

Using the following code:

```
type Message interface {
  FirstLine() string
  /* some other method declarations*/
}

type MessageImpl struct {
  headers     []Header
  /* some other fields */
}

type Request struct {
  MessageImpl
  /* some other fields */
}

type Response struct {
  MessageImpl
  /* some other fields */
}

func (r Request) FirstLine() string {
  var requestLine bytes.Buffer
  requestLine.WriteString("...")
  // Some more instructions
  return requestLine.String()
}


func (m MessageImpl) RenderMessage() string {
  var message bytes.Buffer
  var msg Message = m                   // <=== This is the line the compiler moans about
  message.WriteString(msg.FirstLine())
  // Some more instructions
  return message.String()
}
```

Coming from java language, I'll try to express my intention:
Having some interface `Message` defining some methods implemented by an abstract class `MessageImpl`. Two real classes `Request` and `Response` should inherit from `MessageImpl` (and implement the interface `Message`). Both of these define and implement some more internal methods.

How is this done best?

Comment: Regardless of how you structure it, MessageImpl needs the methods defined in Message to be used as one. That's no different from java.

Comment: It's best not done in Go. Embedding (the language feature you're using) is more equivalent to composition than inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **interface** in go is a set of methods, but interfaces are also types. So the go convention is to suffix -er for any interface to indicate whether or not other types compose methods from it.

You need to define an implementation for the type `Messege` to receive the `FirstLine()` method. It satisfies the `Messeger` interface as a result.

**Edit:**  I misunderstood what you were doing with `bytes.Buffer`, so the answer is actually a lot simpler.

**Edit2:** I had to think about this one a bit but it seems you want `RenderMessage()` to be a function instead of a method. `RenderMessage` has a parameter of type `Messeger` which can (so far) either be of type `Request`, `Response`, or `Message`.

You can't define a method receiver for `RenderMessage` if the `Messager` you're passing can be of variable type, unless you want to have a type switch within `RenderMessage`, which somewhat defeats the purpose of using an interface to begin with.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

type Messager interface {
    FirstLine() string
    /* some other method declarations*/
}

type Header struct {
    Data string
}

type Message struct {
    headers []Header
    /* some other fields */
}

type Request struct {
    /* some fields */
    Message
}

type Response struct {
    /* some fields */
    Message
}

func (r Request) FirstLine() string {
    var requestLine bytes.Buffer
    requestLine.WriteString("...")
    // Some more instructions
    return requestLine.String()
}

func (r Response) FirstLine() string {
    var requestLine bytes.Buffer
    requestLine.WriteString("!!!")
    // Some more instructions
    return requestLine.String()
}

func (m Message) FirstLine() string {
    // whatever this would be
    return "???"
}

func RenderMessage(m Messager) string {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    var msg Messager = m // <=== This is the line the compiler moans about
    b.Write([]byte("some text"))
    b.WriteString(msg.FirstLine())
    // Some more instructions
    return b.String()
}

func main() {
    header := Request{}
    fmt.Println(RenderMessage(header))

    resp := Response{}
    fmt.Println(RenderMessage(resp))

    foo := Message{}
    fmt.Println(RenderMessage(foo))
}
```

Output:

```
some text...
some text!!!
some text???
```

I added this since it wasn't defined in your question:

```
type Header struct {
    Data string
}
```

I also added this line to illustrate the example:

```
    b.Write([]byte("some text"))
```

http://play.golang.org/p/n-DOQbXXl9

Comment: Thank you. As `Message` itself should be abstract, I'm supposed to return an error for calls to `Message.FirstLine()` - this methods should always be implemented by `Request` and `Response` (and other types that may come)